# Evaluating line integral with Stokes' Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

I have to use Stokes' Theorem to evaluate the line integral $$ \int_{\partial S} F \cdot dx $$ where $\partial S$ is the boundary of $$S =\{x^2 +y^2 = z^4,\, 0 \le z \le 3\}$$ and $$F = (xy, y, -2xz^2)^T.$$ I parameterized the boundary curve as $\gamma = (9\cos(t), 9\sin(t), 3)^T$. I defined the region bordered by $\gamma$ as $B$. After applying Stokes' Theorem, I get this surface integral: $$\int_B rot(F) \cdot n \cdot d\sigma.$$ I calculated the rotation of F as $(0, 2z^2, -x)^T$ and the normal vector n as $(0,0,1)^T$. After inserting these values the integral becomes $$\int_B 9\cos(t) \cdot d\sigma = 0.$$ Is this the correct answer or is my calculation wrong? Thank you very much!

Comment: Using $S$ and $B$ for the surface seems to confuse you. If you want to calculate
$$
\int_B{\rm rot}F\cdot\mathbf{n}\,d\Sigma
$$
it will be a *surface* (not a line) integral and the parametrization of its boundary by $\gamma$ won't help.

Comment: I guess the Surface integral had to be $$-\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{9}r^2 \cdot \cos(\phi)\;dr\;d\phi$$ right?

Comment: Yes. That's one way of doing it. A smarter way could be to realize that you integrate an odd function $-x$ over a region that is symmetric around the origin. That integral is therefore zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the end result is correct but find the way it is derived a bit confusing.

> Instead of integrating over the surface $S$ we can take a simpler one with the same boundary: $$B=\{z=3,x^2+y^2\le 81\}\,.$$ The unit normal at this surface is $$\mathbf{n}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\,.$$ The dot product of ${\rm curl}\,F$ with $\mathbf{n}$ is $-x\,.$ Therefore $$\int_B{\rm curl}\,F\,\cdot\mathbf{n}\,d\Sigma=-\int\limits_{x^2+y^2\le 81}x\,dx\,dy=-\int_{-9}^9\int\limits_{-\sqrt{81-y^2}}^{\sqrt{81-y^2}}x\,dx\,dy=0\,.$$